# Understanding Job Tracker Metrics

Tags: hadoop

In my job tracker logs i see the values like

```
2015-01-27 10:04:04,013 [main] INFO 
   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher 
 - detailed locations: 
        M: CDR_IP[1,9],CDR_IP[-1,-1],CDR[17,6],cdrSMS[38,15],
        grpdCdrSMS[47,13],1-11[47,22],cdrMMS[39,14],grpdCdrMMS[53,13],1-12[53,22],
        cdrCALL[40,14],grpdCdrCALL[59,14],1-13[59,23],cdrSMSD[41,14],
        grpdCdrSMSD[64,14],1-14[64,23],cdrMMSD[42,14],grpdCdrMMSD[69,14],1-15[69,23],
        cdrCALLD[43,14],grpdCdrCALLD[74,15],1-16[74,24] 
        C: grpdCdrSMS[47,13],
        1-11[47,22],grpdCdrMMS[53,13],1-12[53,22],grpdCdrCALL[59,14],1-13[59,23],
        grpdCdrSMSD[64,14],1-14[64,23],grpdCdrMMSD[69,14],1-15[69,23],
        grpdCdrCALLD[74,15],1-16[74,24] 
        R: grpdCdrSMS[47,13],UNIONALL[-1,-1],
        grpdCdrMMS[53,13],UNIONALL[-1,-1],grpdCdrCALL[59,14],UNIONALL[-1,-1],
        grpdCdrSMSD[64,14],UNIONALL[-1,-1],grpdCdrMMSD[69,14],UNIONALL[-1,-1],
        grpdCdrCALLD[74,15],UNIONALL[-1,-1]
```

what do values like

```
R: grpdCdrSMS[47,13]
M: CDR_IP[1,9]
UNIONALL[-1,-1]
```

signify.

Answer (score 0):

These look like Pig [relations](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#relations) (bags, tuples and the like), with their respective set values (except `UNIONALL`, obviously, which is an operation). Without more information it is difficult to say exactly.